# MySQL: Directive for all columns to run through substring?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line-interface

I am working with a MySQL database on the CLI which has a few rows that each contain hundreds of characters. I therefore use substring(columnName,1,20) on each one for each query. This is tedious! Is there any directive that I can give so that all queries will run the columns through substring?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a View (once) with the multiple `substring()` calls and then use that view.

Comment: Won't you use a lot of data if you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW TableStripped AS
SELECT AcolumnThatDoesntNeedStripping
     , BcolumnThatDoesntNeedStripping
     , ...
     , SUBSTRING(columnA, 1, 20)
     , SUBSTRING(columnB, 1, 20)
     , SUBSTRING(columnC, 1, 20)
     , ...
     , SUBSTRING(columnZ, 1, 20)
```

and then use that view:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableStripped
```

Comment: @dotancohen: This may be terrible in performance with a big table though. Use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a view for that.

For example, if you have table

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (long_column varchar(8000));
```

I'd create view

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT SUBSTRING(long_column, 1, 20) AS long_column FROM t1;
```

And then rewrite all queries to use `v1.long_column` instead of `SUBSTRING(t1.long_column, 1, 20)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that adds a calculation of substring (1,20) to the list of columns, and then use that calculated column in query expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I had not yet heard of views.