# SQL Select All Columns With Character Limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm making a custom script similar to phpMyAdmin.

I need to use the asterisk (`*`) in order to select all the data in a table without yet knowing the columns. The trick is that I have to limit the amount of data retrieved from each column for efficiency. Basically do this,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Username, 20) FROM Users LIMIT 10
```

Which limits the Username column to *20 characters*, but *I have to do it all at the same time like this*,

```
SELECT SUBSTR(*, 20) FROM Users LIMIT 10
```

How do I select all my data with a specific character limit on each column while using an asterisk?

Comment: there might int types in db table what about them

Comment: You are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687970/mysql-directive-for-all-columns-to-run-through-substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT SUBSTR(COL1,20), SUBSTR(COL2,20),SUBSTR(COL3,20), .... FROM Users LIMIT 10`

You have to limit each column explicitly..

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify all the columns you wish to retreive.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Username,20) as user, SUBSTR(Column2,20) as col, FROM Users LIMIT 10
```

You can't use an asterisk in a mysql function the way you want. Each column has to be limited.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to create a Dynamic SQL, the only things you need are

- Database name
- Table name

Here's the query:

```
SET @db = 'db_2_a8d87';   -- database name
SET @tb = 'Table1';       -- table name
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUBSTRING(',column_Name,',1,3)', column_Name)) INTO @sql
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = @db AND table_name = @tb;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM ', @tb);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d87/14)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can do this in two parts.  For the first part, run:

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN Users;
```

Then use the results in the Field column of that query to programmatically generate a second query selecting each of the column names returned in the first query.